# Creating different Origins for Object Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've established an array of 3 groups of 3 particles. I bleive it has to do with altering the code portion below.

```
>     let particles; 
>       function init(){
>         particles=[];
>         for(let i=0; i<2;i+=1){
>           for(var j=0; j<2;j+=1){
>           particles.push(new Particle(centerX, centerY)); }
>         console.log(particles);}
>       console.log(particles);
>       }
```

The particles are currently locate in the same position right now. Is there a way to shift the origin of each particle by 50 both in x and y? Here is the full code:

```js
    window.onload =function(){
    
      var canvas = document.createElement ("canvas");
    
      c = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
      canvas.width = 400; 
      canvas.height=400; 
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      c.beginPath();
      c.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      c.fillStyle = "white";
      c.fill();
      c.closePath();
      var  centerX=canvas.width/2; 
      var centerY=canvas.width/2;
      
      function Particle(centerX, centerY){
       
     
         this.centerX=canvas.width/2; 
         this.centerY=canvas.width/2;    
         this.radians=0;
     
         this.update=function(){
            this.radians+=.1;
            this.centerX=this.centerX+Math.sin(this.radians)*2;
            this.centerY=this.centerY+Math.cos(this.radians)*2;
            this.draw();
             };
        this.draw=function(){
            c. beginPath(); 
            c.arc(this.centerX,this.centerY,5,0,2*Math.PI);
            c.fillStyle='black';
            c.fill()
             }
        }
    
      let particles; 
      function init(){
      particles=[];
      for(let i=0; i<2;i+=1){
          for(var j=0; j<2;j+=1){       
              particles.push(new Particle(centerX, centerY));   
          }
       }   
      }
    function animate (){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        c.fillStyle = "white";
        c.fill();
        c.closePath();
        particles.forEach(particle=>{
            particle.update();
            });
        }
    init();
    animate();
                         
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you cleanup your code first: (like var, let), your using "this" as reference so why didn't you use an arrow function? () => {}. Also c.<space>beginPath(); isn't going to work. What it also makes more readable is using i++ instead of i += 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - I change lines

```
 this.centerX=canvas.width/2; 
 this.centerY=canvas.width/2;
```

to

```
 this.centerX=centerX;
 this.centerY=centerY;
```

and line `particles.push(new Particle(centerX, centerY));`  to

```
particles.push(new Particle(centerX+i*50, centerY+j*50));
```

(and in that `for` loops which wrap this line change `i<2` to `i<=2` and similar with j) Run snippet and scroll down to see

```js
window.onload =function(){

  var canvas = document.createElement ("canvas");

  c = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
  canvas.width = 400; 
  canvas.height=400; 
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  c.beginPath();
  c.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.fillStyle = "white";
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
  var  centerX=canvas.width/2; 
  var centerY=canvas.width/2;

  function Particle(centerX, centerY){

     this.centerX=centerX;
     this.centerY=centerY;
     this.radians=0;

     this.update=function(){
        this.radians+=.1;
        this.centerX=this.centerX+Math.sin(this.radians)*2;
        this.centerY=this.centerY+Math.cos(this.radians)*2;
        this.draw();
         };
    this.draw=function(){
        c. beginPath(); 
        c.arc(this.centerX,this.centerY,5,0,2*Math.PI);
        c.fillStyle='black';
        c.fill()
         }
    }

  let particles; 
  function init(){
  particles=[];
  for(let i=0; i<=2;i+=1){
      for(var j=0; j<=2;j+=1){       
          particles.push(new Particle(centerX+i*50, centerY+j*50));   
      }
   }   
  }
function animate (){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();
    particles.forEach(particle=>{
        particle.update();
        });
    }
init();
animate();

}
```